# Find a basis for the vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let the following be a vector space:
> $$\langle t^5, t^5+t^2,t^5+1, t^5+t^2+1,t^6+t^4 \rangle \subset \mathbb{R}[t]$$

I am still wrapping my head around monomial bases but my intuition tells be that the following should be a basis for the vector space:

$$\{1,t^2,t^4,t^5,t^6\}$$

If that is correct, how would I test it and find the basis more systematically?

Comment: Write the vectors in the basis $\{1,t,t^2,t^3,t^4,t^5,t^6\}$, put the coordinates in the rows of a matrix, and reduce it to row echelon form.

Comment: @lhf I am not sure how I should go about doing that. What is exactly a vector in this case?

Comment: Your basis is correct. To show that it is a basis, first show that any of the vectors in your generating set can be expressed as a linear combination of the elements of the basis. Then argue that all of them are needed to get the generating set.

Comment: See [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=row+reduce+%7B%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C0%7D%2C+%7B0%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C1%7D%7D), which confirms the answer by @BatMath in a systematic way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basis can be given by $\mathcal B :=(1,t^2,t^5,t^6+t^4)$. Indeed, we can easily prove that
$$
\langle \mathcal B\rangle =
\langle 
t^5,t^5+t^2,t^5+1,t^5+t^2+1,t^6+t^4
\rangle
$$
To see that the family $\mathcal B$ is linearly independent (free) it suffices to see that it is a family of polynomials scaled in degree.

Here is a more detailed answer:

To simplify notations, we write
$$
\left\{
\begin{matrix}
 e_0 = t^5\\
e_1 = t^5+t^2 \\
e_2 = t^5+1 \\
e_3 = t^5+t^2+1 \\
e_4 = t^6+t^4
\end{matrix}
\right.\quad \hbox{and}\quad 
\left\{
\begin{matrix}
 b_0 = 1\\
b_1 = t^2 \\
b_2 = t^5 \\
b_3 = t^6+t^4
\end{matrix}
\right.
$$
Our goal is to show that $\mathcal B := (b_0,b_1,b_2,b_3)$ is a basis of $F :=\langle e_0,e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4\rangle$.

The first step is to show that it spans our space -- that is $\langle \mathcal B\rangle = F$ (be careful, we need to show both inclusions $\langle \mathcal B\rangle \subset F$ and $\langle \mathcal B\rangle \supset F$, you do not want your basis to span a space that would be "too big").

The inclusion, $\langle \mathcal B\rangle \subset F$ follows from the identities
\begin{align*}
b_0 &= e_3-e_1\in F; \\
b_1 &= e_1-e_0\in F; \\
b_2 &= e_0\in F; \\
b_3 &= e_4\in F.
\end{align*}
The other inclusion $\langle \mathcal B\rangle \supset F$ follows from similar computations.

Now let us show it is linearly independent. Let $\alpha_0,\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3$ be scalars such that $\alpha_0b_0+\alpha_1b_1+\alpha_2b_2+\alpha_3b_3 = 0$. Then we have
$$
P(t) :=
\alpha_0+\alpha_1t^2 + \alpha_2t^5+\alpha_3(t^6+t^4) = 0.
$$
Two polynomials are equal if and only if they have same coefficients so it must mean that all $\alpha_i$'s are zeros. Indeed, we can recursively derivate the polynomial and evaluate each derivative at zero, this gives:
\begin{align*}
\alpha_0 &= P(0) = 0, \\
2\alpha_1 &= P^{(2)}(0) = 0,\\
4!\alpha_3 &= P^{(4)}(0) = 0,\\
5!\alpha_2 &= P^{(5)}(0) = 0.
\end{align*}
This implies linear independence of the family $\mathcal B$.

As an exercise, you can show that any family of polynomials $(P_1,...,P_n)$ in $\mathbb R[t]$ whose polynomials each have different degree is linearly free (if you want to show this using calculus as I did above, you can do this by induction for instance).

Comment: Could you elaborate how that is a Basis?

Comment: I edited my answer. It should be more complet.

Comment: Thank you very much, I don't understand however as to why the coefficients turn out to be zero? Which 'Two ' polynomials do you mean exactly?

Comment: Let me add some more details.

Comment: The two polynomials I was referring to were P and 0.

Comment: Thank you very much! Is the basis I gave in my question, i.e. $\{1,t^2,t^4,t^5,t^6\}$, not correct?

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't. If it were, you would be able to express $t^4$ or $t^6$ as a linear combination of the $e_i$'s (as defined in my answer). You can try and check that this is impossible.